# Need to wait for a Prop to be ready before reaching out to Firebase

Tags: vue.js, vuefire

Using vue2 + vue-router + vuefire + firebase

In the following code the Firebase source for "schedule" requires "this.settings.season" in the path, which is provided in the "settings" prop, but not ready when the page loads.  If I navigate away (within the SPA) and back then the schedule data loads, since "settings" is ready.

How can I wait for the 'settings' prop to be ready before retrieving the 'schedule'?

```
<script>  
const seasonsRef = db.ref('league/-KonukQ9Pf7ksy9jvgo3/seasons')

export default {
    name: 'userleague',
    props: ['settings'],
    data() {
        return {
            scheduleready: false,
        }
    },
    firebase() {
        return {
            schedule: {
                source: seasonsRef.child(this.settings.season).child('schedule'),
                asObject: false,
                readyCallback: function() {
                    this.scheduleready = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</Script>
```